How to make AndroidStudio see my xposed imports?
Currently trying to build my own Xposed module, but got a issue that project can't see my dependencies with that error:
/home/***/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/MainHook.java:3: error: package de.robv.android does not exist
import static de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage;
                             ^
/home/***/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/MainHook.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage;
^
/home/***/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/MainHook.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainHook implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
                                 ^
  symbol: class IXposedHookLoadPackage
/home/***/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/MainHook.java:7: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^

That's my MainHook code:
package com.example.myapplication;

import static de.robv.android.xposed.IXposedHookLoadPackage;
import de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge;
import de.robv.android.xposed.callbacks.XC_LoadPackage;
public class MainHook implements IXposedHookLoadPackage {
    @Override
    public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
        if (!lpparam.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.my.another.application")) return;
        XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
        }
}

How to make AndroidStudio to see that package and use it?
What I did:

Put in build.gradle those lines:

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82'
    compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82:sources'
}


Added that in AndroidManifest:

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedmodule"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposeddescription"
            android:value="Please, Omnissian, let me build it" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedminversion"
            android:value="53" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedscope"
            android:resource="@array/xposedscope"/>
    </application>


Added that in settings.gradle

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://api.xposed.info/' }
    }
}


Created folder assets and added file xposed_init inside with that content:

com.example.myapplication.MainHook

Gradle can see that package:
image1

The artifact de.robv.android.xposed:api:82 seems to exist in the repo 'https://api.xposed.info/however there seems to be a problem with the integrity data. If I try to download the artifact via Maven I get an rorg.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, no checksums available for the command mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get -DrepoUrl=https://api.xposed.info/ -Dartifact=de.robv.android.xposed:api:82 Not sure what Gradle does in such a case.

I redid the same things, by copying configs from here and built project with such errors:
Cannot resolve symbol 'IXposedHookLoadPackage'
Cannot resolve symbol 'XposedBridge'
Cannot resolve symbol 'XC_LoadPackage'
Cannot resolve symbol 'XC_MethodHook'

But LSPosed just accepted it and module is working.
Seems like the problem was in AndroidStudio, so to be sure if your code doesn't work you need to try this on device first.

I removed the compileOnly 'de.robv.android.xposed:api:82:sources' line and it started working perfectly in Android Studio. As per here it's not required unless you want to see the source code of Xposed itself, and at least for me the sources got downloaded automatically anyway with just the one line. Probably related to a newer Gradle feature.
